# How can I programatically fill a flash drive with my latest photos from iPhoto?

Tags: backup, photos.app

Suppose I want to fill up a flash drive with the most recent photos in my iPhoto Library.

- I want to end up with an external drive that has all my photos in a single directory (no nested folders)
- Those photos that have been modified, I want the modified version of the photo to end up on the drive.
- Those photos that have not been modified, I want the original version of the photo to end up on the drive
- I want to start with the newest photo and work backward in time, so when the drive fills up, the latest photos will be included on the external drive.
- I fully expect that the external drive cannot hold all the pictures in my library. Any warning to this effect must be non-modally, and not prevent the script from proceeding to fill the drive with the newest photos in my library, then halt gracefully when the disk is full.
- I want to do this programmatically (shell or AppleScript), **without** launching iPhoto.

Does anyone know how to go about doing this? I've written some shell scripts over the years, but none of them quite work the way I'd hoped.

I suspect the right answer will involve some copying and some "if" statements.

Comment: While I suspect it's possible to open the iPhoto library bundle and traverse it's directory structure this seems a fragile and error-prone method of "backup". I would assure I had adequate disk space and back up the iPhoto library by *making a copy of the* iPhoto Library *file*.

Comment: @jaberg For many steps of my backup, of course that's what I do. Time Machine, etc. But photos are special. I regularly store the most recent n GB of photos on a flash drive off-site. This is in addition to my normal backup routine. If I lose the drafts of my review of Markdown for the AD blog, oh well. If I lose photos of my kids, that's a problem. This is an extra step of backup.

Comment: Point taken. My digital photos were the motivation behind my developing my own backup strategy—SuperDuper! and Crashplan Central. That being said, it's the very importance of those files that causes me to question an "unsupported" script-based backup system. There is no easy way to sort out the exact files you want, and the complexity of the system is what makes it delicate.

Comment: I'd suggest you get Amazon S3 and Arq (http://www.haystacksoftware.com/arq/) and backup all your photos ;)

Comment: Shouldn't this be on Stack Overflow? wink wink

Comment: @bmike I was expecting an AppleScript, Automator action, or shell script. The answer I got indeed might be more on-topic for another site, but the question is relevant here, and the problem appears to have been solved.

Comment: I'm just poking fun - hope its ok to explore the bounds of the FAQ by taking light-hearted pot-shots at my fellow moderators.

Comment: @bmike Of course it's okay. I'm not great at reading tone in comments, so I was just clarifying, and hoping the question wasn't about to get closed before I assigned the bounty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have written a script to do this for you. It is available [here](https://github.com/kylecronin/iPhoto-Backup). It works with system Ruby (1.8.6 in Lion) with no external dependencies. This is how you use it (also included in the README):

> This script looks for an iPhoto '11 album data file in
>
> ```
> ~/Pictures/iPhoto Library/AlbumData.xml
> ```
>
> This is the standard place for iPhoto to store the album data file, so
>   it's very likely you have it here if you have iPhoto.
>
> Recommended use for the script is to copy it to wherever you wish to
>   backup the files to, then invoke it on the command line:
>
> ```
> $ruby iphoto.rb
> ```
>
> This will scan the album data file, sort the photos by date, newest
>   first, then copy them to the desired destination until the drive is
>   full. Alternatively, you can manually specify the path you wish to
>   copy to as an argument parameter, in case you want to store the script
>   somewhere else:
>
> ```
> $ruby iphoto.rb /Volumes/Backup
> ```
>
> This script was written with exactly one user in mind; that is why it
>   has no other options.
>
> ---
>
> - I have tested this on exactly one iPhoto library: mine. It works for me, but YMMV.
> - The number in front of the files is the "DateAsTimerInterval" value from the album data file. I don't know how to convert it to a "real" date, but sorting by it does sort chronologically, so it's good enough for the purposes of this script.

Comment: P.S. Please no comments on coding style or whatever, this was one of those projects where I stopped once it worked. And yes, it does use a regex to parse XML - again, it works, and I didn't find a built-in XML lib I liked (I didn't want to add dependencies)

Comment: If a picture was modified your script will also copy the original - right ?

Comment: @iolsmit As per Daniel's specs, the script will not copy the original if it was modified